# '/' understood as a float?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am looping through a pandas dataframe and trying to append the result on a conditional statement. However, my code seems to be posing a problem stopping me from append  what I want although it prints fine but displays the error in the end. here is my code below:

```
counta=[]
for line in ipcm_perf['Alarms']:
    if '/' in line:
       print (line)
```

the error I get is the following :

```
     2 for line in ipcm_perf['Alarms']:
     ----> 3     if ('/') in line:
           4         print (line)
           5 

         TypeError: argument of type 'float' is not iterable
```

I really do not know why Python is flagging that line. where's the float? Everything is being printed but with error at the bottom. It is stopping from appending.

Comment: `line` is the float, not `'/'`.

Comment: Can you provide `ipcm_perf`?

Comment: ipcm_perf is the dataframe I am pulling the data from.  That is just the column.

Comment: why am I being voted down?

Comment: have you tried to write `if '/' in 3.14: print("something")`? it may return an error you recognize

Comment: @Gsk it is coming back with the same error. Is it python 3???

Comment: @interjay ipcm_perf['Alarms'] is a column containing texts

Comment: @Camue If it was then you wouldn't get an error on that line. `line` is clearly a float.

Answer (score 0):

your problem is that you are trying to check if there is a string (`/`) in a floating number (`line`), and Python does not like that.
That's because when you write `"/" in some_string` Python iterates through each char of `some_string`, but he can iterate through a floating number.
you can double check this by simply running:

```
if '/' in 3.14:
    print("something")
```

**output:**

> TypeError: argument of type 'float' is not iterable

I suppose that you're searching for a `/` because you've seen that somewhere in the column. If that's the case, it probably is in a `string`, and if that's the case, a quick&dirty way to clean your data can be:

```
if type(line) == str:
    if "/" in line:
        print(line)
else:
    print("I am not a string")
```

and with `line = 3.14`, it returns:

> I am not a string

and with `line = "4/2"`, it returns:

> I am a string

Comment: There is only texts in that column. But I just ran the code as well. All of them are string without any exception.

Comment: out of curiosity, can you try to run the code now? does it raise an error?